# Unique words in String

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hiii Friends,
I have a String like;

****String s="
POWER TRANSFER UNIT PX SWITCH BLEEDING 2 HYDRAULIC SYSTEM ENGINE START GREEN POWER TRANSFER UNIT LIGHT";****

This String is formed with the help of **two columns of a table from a database**.
As you can see that there is a **UNIT** in that String which comes twice in the String. My requirement is that, a word must be unique in the String.
If a word comes twice or more than twice, it should not append in the String.The formed String must have unique words.
Please help me out in this.

Comment: I suggest you that from database take unique strings... "Select distinct word from wordsTable" somewhat like this.

Comment: I really don't have an idea how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short solution for copy-past.**

```
private String deleteNonUniqueWords(String str) {    
    Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+")));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : result) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Usage of method:

```
String s = "POWER TRANSFER UNIT PX SWITCH BLEEDING 2 HYDRAULIC SYSTEM ENGINE START GREEN POWER TRANSFER UNIT LIGHT";
System.out.print(deleteNonUniqueWords(s))
```

Output:

```
POWER TRANSFER UNIT PX SWITCH BLEEDING 2 HYDRAULIC SYSTEM ENGINE START GREEN LIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the trickiest bit here is segmenting the string into words. You haven't really defined what a "word" is, and depending on the internationalization story, this may be either very easy or very difficult (for example, if your definition of a word is very English-centric and you only need to split on spaces, then it should be a very easy task; however, if you need to account for CJK languages where multiple ideographs may be separate "words" but are not separated by spaces, this can be very difficult).

Assuming that you have a word segmenting function such that you can do:

```
for (String word : getWordsIn(originalString)) {
  // ...
}
```

... it should be trivial for you to determine uniqueness with a `Set` datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a List
2. Split String
3. Foreach word in String 
   is word in list? 
   no: put word in list 
   yes: ignore

Answer (score 0):

First option at database level using distinct:
Dummy query for the same

```
 "Select distinct word from wordsTable"
```

Second option:

```
 String[] words=s.split("\\s+");
 Set<String> uniqueStringSet=new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(words))

 String havingUniqueWords="";

 for(String word:uniqueStringSet){

     havingUniqueWords=havingUniqueWords+word;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could find duplicated words (note that Lucene is not used):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(\\w++)(?=.*\\1)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" POWER TRANSFER UNIT PX SWITCH BLEEDING 2 HYDRAULIC SYSTEM ENGINE START GREEN POWER TRANSFER UNIT LIGHT");
Set<String> duplicatedWords = new HashSet<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    duplicatedWords.add(m.group(1));
}
```